# Number of solutions of $\cos^5x+\cos^5\left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + \cos^5\left( x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) =0$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

> Solve in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ : $$\cos^5x+\cos^5\left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + \cos^5\left( x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)=0 $$

I tried expanding the L.H.S by applying the formula of $\cos(A+B)$ but it results in a quintic polynomial in terms of $\cos x $. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Power%5Bcos%2C5%5Dx%2B+Power%5Bcos%2C5%5D%5C%2840%29x%2B2Divide%5B%CF%80%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29%2BPower%5Bcos%2C5%5D%5C%2840%29x%2B4Divide%5B%CF%80%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29%3D0) has simplified the left hand side all the way to $\frac{15}{16}\cos3x$ but I'm unable to think of any method to reach there.

Comment: There would be infinite solutions unless you restrict the domain of $x$, right? Since the function is periodic?

Comment: As said @DhanviSreenivasan since $x\mapsto \cos(x)$ is a periodic function, we have infinite solutions. Also, since LHS=$\cos(3x)$ so $x=-\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{3}n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swatting this fly with an oversized mallet.

Let
$$f(x)=\cos^5x+\cos^5\left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + \cos^5\left( x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right).$$
Because cosine has period $2\pi$, we easily see that $f(x)$ has period $2\pi/3$. It is well behaved (continuously differentiable), so it can be expanded into a Fourier series.
The function $f(x)$ is even, $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, so the expansion only contains cosine terms.
As you observed, it is a quintic polynomial in $\cos x$, so
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^5a_k\cos kx
$$
for some constants $a_k\in\Bbb{R}$. Period $2\pi/3$ implies that $a_k=0$ unless $k$ is divisible by three. At this point we know that
$$f(x)=a_0+a_3\cos 3x$$
for some constants $a_0,a_3$. We have
$f(x+\pi)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ implying that $a_0=0$ (you can see this also by observing that only odd powers of $\cos x$ occur in that quintic, or by observing that $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,dx=0$).

Last but not least
$$a_3=f(0)=1+(-1/2)^5+(-1/2)^5=15/16.$$
So
$$f(x)=\frac{15}{16}\cos 3x.$$

Comment: Observe that the substitutions $x\to -x$ and $x\to x+\pi$ both map the zero phase shift term to its constant ($\pm1$) multiple, but interchange the other two terms. The net effect on the sum is as described.

Comment: How is the period $2\pi/3$

Comment: @Upstart Plug in $x+2\pi/3$ to see why $2\pi/3$ is a period.

Comment: Okay I see. But how is it even

Comment: @Upstart Good job! It's even because cosine is even: $\cos(-x)=\cos x$ and by the same rule and periodicity
$$\cos(-x+2\pi/3)=\cos(x-2\pi/3)=\cos(x-2\pi/3+2\pi)=\cos(x+4\pi/3).$$
Similarly $\cos(-x+4\pi/3)=\cos(x+2\pi/3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Use $\cos (A+B)$ formula to show for a natural number $n$,

$$\cos nx + \cos \left(nx+\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right) + \cos \left(nx+\frac{4n\pi}{3}\right) = \begin{cases} 0 , \quad \text{when n is coprime to 3} \\ 3\cos nx , \quad \text{when n is a multiple of 3} \end{cases}$$

Combining this with the identity from other answer,

$$\cos^5 \theta = \frac{1}{16}\cos 5\theta + \frac{5}{16}\cos  3\theta + \frac{10}{16}\cos  \theta$$

it is easy to see that first and third terms, $n=1,5$, should sum to zero, while middle term remains to give

$$\cos^5x+\cos^5\left( x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + \cos^5\left( x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{15}{16}\cos  3x$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\cos^5\theta =\frac{ 10 \cos(θ) + 5 \cos(3 θ) + \cos(5 θ)}{16}$$because  $$\cos^5 x=1/32{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}^5=\frac{e^{5ix}+e^{-5ix}+5(e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix})+10(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{32}$$

Note that there will be infinitely many solutions as pointed out in comments

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the roots of $$4c^3-3c-\cos3x=0$$ are $c_r\cos(x+2r\pi/3), r=0,1,2$

Let $p=c_0,c_1=q,c_2=r$

$p+q+r=0\implies p^3+q^3+r^3=3pqr$

$pq+qr+rp=-3/4\implies p^2+q^2+r^2=0^2-2(-3/4)$

$pqr=\dfrac{\cos3x}4$

As $4c^5=3c^3+c^2\cos3x,$

$4(p^5+q^5+r^5)$

$=3(p^3+q^3+r^3)+(p^2+q^2+r^2)\cos3x$

Replace the values of $p^3+q^3+r^3, p^2+q^2+r^2$